# remove specific keys from php array with wildcard

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to search an array for a specific partial string and remove all the keys containing them. I have tried several things and my PHP-fu is running out here...

The array i am searching (partial but much along these lines) is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /.
    [1] => /..
    [2] => /htdocs
    [3] => /htdocs/.
    [4] => /htdocs/..
    [5] => /htdocs/zipper_new.php
    [6] => /htdocs/bottom.gif
)
```

I am trying to remove all of the entries containing "/." and "/..".

The long and short of it is i made a script to search for files by file type and tar them, i am trying to add functionality to instead search for all the files and do the same, This part is failing citing the entries containing those strings whether in whole or part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    '/.',
    '/..',
    '/htdocs',
    '/htdocs/.',
    '/htdocs/..',
    '/htdocs/zipper_new.php',
    '/htdocs/bottom.gif',
);

$match = '/.';

$newData = array_filter(
    $data,
    function($value) use ($match) {
        return (!fnmatch('*' . $match . '*', $value));
    }
);

var_dump($newData);
```

Comment: I had tried array_filter() but seems i definitely wasn't using it the right way :) thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Can't you simply use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop and look for your string with a function like [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) ?

And then, remove the entry with [unset](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```
foreach ($table as $key => $item) {
    if (strstr($item, '/.')) // If it contains /. it will also match for /..
        unset($table[$key]);
}
```